# simplexml not sure how to access attribute value of tag

Tags: php, simplexml

I have an xml file. Here's how it's formed:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<export>
    <config>
        <exported_values>
            <value1>Dog</value1>
            <value2>Cat</value2>
            <value3>Bird</value3>
            <value4>Mouse</value4>
        </exported_values>

        <item name="orange" text="this is item 1" />
        <item name="blue" text="this is item 2" />
        <item name="yellow" text="this is item 3" />
        <item name="green" text="this is item 4" />
    </config>
</export>
```

How can i access the value of name inside item? I tried this without luck:

```
if( ! $xml = simplexml_load_file('xml/test.xml') ){
    echo 'unable to load XML file';
} else {
    foreach( $xml as $item )
    {
        echo 'item: '.$item->config->item['name'].'<br />';
    } 
}
```

But that does not return anything. Did i miss something?

Comment: Your XML is invalid. None of your closing tags are actually closed.

Comment: You should be getting a couple dozen warnings plus "unable to load XML file" :-? Is this your real code?

Comment: No sorry, the info is sensitive so i didnt include the actual file. Ill correct the non closing of tags

Comment: Ok i retested it and the file loads fine now. Dont the get the error but item returns nothing so im guessing this is an issue with the code rather than xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the way you're trying to access the attributes from your XML nodes. Just update your foreach code to:

```
foreach( $xml->config->item as $item )
{
    echo 'item: ', $item->attributes()->name, '<br />';
}
```

#### Output:

```
item: orange<br />item: blue<br />item: yellow<br />item: green<br />
```

#### [Working demo](http://codepad.org/JrOk0RoL).

Comment: There's no need to resort to the verbosity of `->attributes()` here, you can just use `$item['name']`: http://codepad.org/5ZhuAUP9.

Answer (score 1):

You have `$item->config->item` and `$item` the wrong way around: the `<config>` item only appears once, so accessing it every time round the loop would make no sense.

`$xml` represents the `<export>` node, and you want to loop over each of the several `<item>` nodes in the single `<config>` node, so the loop should be:

```
foreach( $xml->config->item as $item )
```

Then `$item` will represent each particular `<item>` node in the loop, so accessing the attribute will be as simple as:

```
echo $item['name'];
```

Here's [a complete live example](http://codepad.org/5ZhuAUP9).